Good PDE textbooks that contains the usage of distribution theory to study wave equations
I have learned some basic PDE theories, and now I want to learn further properties of wave equations by using distribution theory, which contains fourier transform, convolution of distribution and so on, the book I'm currently reading, which is Shubin's , doesn't treat wave equations by starting with fourier transform of equations and solution of fundamental solution, so could you please recommend some textbooks on PDE that use distribution theory? thank you

Look at Folland’s PDE book. Also, consider Francois Treves’, Basic Linear Partial Differential Equations (a book Folland cites occasionally).

Based on your description, I would recommend Lieb and Loss's Analysis, with a focus on how Fourier analysis and distribution theory are used in solving PDE.

It seems that this book don’t contain special treat of PDE

@YuerCauchy I am looking at my 1st ed, and Chapters 7-10 of this book are all about PDEs, Poisson, Schrodinger, Sobolev embeddings and its usage in determining the regularity of solutions. Fourier transforms in the context of Schwartz spaces, etc.
